# Crear otra columna con datos de una columna de la misma tabla SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-management

Buen dia, tengo una duda y es como les mencionaba en la pregunta me gustaria sacar otra columna con datos de otra columna de mi misma tabla es decir tengo esta tabla como ejemplo:

```
ID     Docente                        Años      JefeID
1      Jose Maria Jimenez               34          5
2      Erika Gonzales Muñoz             32          5
3      Juan Carlos Herrera              28       Null  
4      Maria Jose Lopez Ramirez         43          8
5      Ricardo Zamarripa Delgado        25          5
6      Alejandro Hernandez Castillo     34          8
7      Paola Contreras Fernandez        41       Null
8      Luis Alberto Gutierrez Macias    40          7
```

Y me gustaria sacar en otra columna el nombre del jefe del docente, es decir traer el nombre de la columna 'Docente' de acuerdo al 'JefeID' en la nueva columna para que quede algo asi:

```
ID     Docente                        Años      JefeID    NombreJefe
1      Jose Maria Jimenez               34          5     Maria Jose Lopez Ramirez
2      Erika Gonzales Muñoz             32          5     Maria Jose Lopez Ramirez
3      Juan Carlos Herrera              28       Null     Null
4      Maria Jose Lopez Ramirez         43          8     Luis Alberto Gutierrez Macias
5      Ricardo Zamarripa Delgado        25          5     Maria Jose Lopez Ramirez
6      Alejandro Hernandez Castillo     34          8     Luis Alberto Gutierrez Macias
7      Paola Contreras Fernandez        41       Null     Null
8      Luis Alberto Gutierrez Macias    40          7     Paola Contreras Fernandez
```

Comment: Tenés que hacer un left join sobre la misma tabla: `select A.*, B.Docente from tabla A left join tabla B ON A.JefeId = B.Id`

Comment: @PatricioMoracho como? osea lo que quiero es sacar el nombre de la misma tabla

Comment: Y eso es lo que te indique en mi comentàrio, reemplaza `tabla` por el nombre real de tu tabla

Comment: @PatricioMoracho ok, entonces más bien no entendi perdon, entonces la tabla A y tabla B seria la misma tabla con la que trabajo?

Comment: @PatricioMoracho Listo, si se pudo te lo agradezco mucho... ahora solo otra pregunta, se puede hacer lo mismo pero de la columna nueva que se saco?

Comment: no entendí  tu último comentario.

Comment: Es decir, cuando saco el nombre del jefe traer el nombre de su jefe, en este caso dando como ejemplo datos de la tabla que comparti si saco en nombre del jefe de 'Jose' seria 'Maria Jose' y si quisiera sacar ahora el nombre del jefe de 'Maria Jose' que seria 'Luis Alberto' como tendria que hacerlo?

Comment: O sea quieres extraer de "Maria Jose Lopez Ramirez" solo la parte del nombre es decir Maria Jose?

Comment: No, osea del select que me pasaste ya se saco el nombre de "Maria Jose Lopez Ramirez" ahora quiero sacar el nombre del jefe de ella que seria "Luis Alberto Gutierrez Macias" no se si me di a entender... para que en total quede el nombre del docente, el jefe del docente y el jefe del jefe del docente.

Comment: A ver, estoy confundido,  la consulta que te pase, muestra todos los "Docentes" y al lado te debería mostrar los datos del docente que es jefe (si corresponde) , el alias A representa los docentes y el alias B representa a los jefes, si muestra la columna B.Docente no te estaría mostrando el nombre del Jefe? no es eso lo que quieres?

Comment: Si asi es, pero si quisiera sacar un alias C con el nombre del jefe del Alias B como seria? hacer un left join de nuevo?

Comment: O sea un jefe del jefe? agrega otro left join con el alias C y relaciona el jefeId de B con el id de C